# Please make an optional $1/month no-ad version of the site

Tags: feature-request, advertising, payment

Please make an optional $1/month membership level!

I never click the ads... my "ad" worth to the site must be less than $1 per month.

Make the paid version of the site **exactly** the same as the non-paid version.

I am willing to pay $1 per month just to have the ads removed.

Make this **optional**. If you want to pay, okay... if you don't, you'll see some ads (keeping it cool... not too many).

Comment: And yet people protested when Geocities was taken down ...

Comment: I never used geocities daily... i do use stackoverflow daily.
It's optional anyway...

Comment: After you get a little more reputation most of the ads will go away. 3 more thoughtful answers and you're done with the ads.

Comment: You can download browser add-ons such as AdBlock that completely remove all ads, for free.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The plentitude of ads you are seeing is because you do not have 200 reputation points yet. Achieve those, and the number of ads will dwindle down to one in the right hand side bar.

I'm pretty sure you will find it's totally acceptable, and so un-annoying that you would hardly see an incentive to pay $1 a month. Also, most frequent users would probably hardly accept to have to *pay* to deliver their quality content that makes the site run!

The way it currently is, users with less activity (and subsequently, reputation points) will see more ads, and the more you contribute, the less ads you get.

Comment: Exactly, rather than paying with a ridiculous amount of money, pay with something more valuable to the world: **answers**

Answer (score 12):

No no no. These sites never need to be mixed up with paid sites, other wise we just have another experts-exchange...

And also it doesn't matter if you click the ads, what matters is that you see them. Advertisers pay for both views and clicks, not just one or the other..

Oh and also, the ads here aren't even bad! I even have been known to click a few because they genuinely interest me.. If you really dislike them though then just install Ad-Block-Plus..

Comment: Also, when you get a bit more rep on SO, you won't see nearly as many of them.

Comment: hmm... i said it was optional... it's a feature request... not somekind of business model change.

Comment: The problem with the ads is not that they're there, it's just that they're useless. No "usefull" or "informative" ads anywhere.
All is see are award winnning controls...

Comment: @basil yes those are the more often ones(Telerik, I hate thee) but every once in a while you'll see something actually cool.. plus they run open source ads too

Comment: @devin Oops it was just a typo ;)

Answer (score 5):

Your $1 turns you from a 'may click' to a 'never gonna click you up, never gonna ..", ah never mind. Sorry about the rickroll, but you did end a question with an exclamation point.

For SO (and the rest of the SE sites) to survive, some ads need to be shown. Your participation is worth its weight in gold, your $1 is not. The price per spot depends on how many people are actually going to *see* the ad. And then you have a site just for programmers .. ugh, that's a hard sell to begin with.

Something has to pay for the bandwidth, servers, programmers, Robert, rent, etc. Even if every single (active) user on SO contributed $1 per month, SO would be in the red. Lets define active as people with 200+ rep. That's someone participating for a week or two, or the next stellar user participating for a day. I think that's fair for the purposes of this answer.

I (almost) never click ads, however SO has been supporting free/open source software in its advertisements for a while now. Every time I view the site, I see another project that I might be interested in trying, perhaps helping. And then there is that 'case of the Mondays' woman, I can't defend that.

What I can defend is the fact that SO needs money to operate and exists to serve its advertised purpose, helping people solve programming problems. Many other sites exist to serve ads, while pretending to do something else.

After you reach 200 rep, you'll see some ads in the side bar. That's it, no more, no less. Effectively, SO could be showing you more ads, since it means more impressions. They aren't doing that. Sure, yes, they can show you more targeted ads as you refine your tag preferences, but:

- You might actually find them interesting
- Again, you see very few ads after reaching 200 rep.

Just because Slashdot thought it was a good idea doesn't mean it is.

You can, after all, not click on them.

Comment: There is **no** defense for the "case of the Mondays" ad. But the rest is all true.

Comment: @George - I actually saw that woman in my sleep. As I said, there's no defense.

Comment: @George - waking from a bad dream and calling your wife subjective and argumentative, however .. is another point.

Comment: @Tim you should totally drop her and try jQuery

Comment: @Tim, I wondered if your numbers were off, so I counted the pages of users with 200+ rep, which is 721. So that's a total of 25,235 users. That's $25K/month ($300K/year). So you could be right, it depends on what their total expenses are. :) But are you saying *ad revenue* is pulling in more than 300K, from the sub-200 rep users only? Wow.

Comment: You are absolutely right. But ok, it admit, let's make it two dollars. I actually canceled my cable TV subscription so i have 20$ each month to spare.
This site provides a service. I love it.

Comment: How come this isn't [tag:status-declined]?

Answer (score 3):

Use adblock and request a donation-button

Comment: Or Patreon subscription perhaps.

Comment: @WilliamIsted Sure, or that indeed. Not that it existed back in 2010 ;)

Comment: someone has to keep these answers relevant :P