# Inappropriate weight loss ad on The Workplace, ELU, and Travel

Tags: support, advertising

Technically I guess this might be site-specific (so migrate if needed), but as [the official announcement on ads](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/329763/398063) says the following, I'm reporting it here for the time being<sup>1</sup>. Additionally, the way I understand it, this ad could be triggered anywhere on the network.

> If you see any ads that are inappropriate or have any questions about this experiment, please let me know by starting a new question and tagging it with [advertising](/questions/tagged/advertising).

I just witnessed this ad on the Workplace:

> [image: weight loss ad in French]

```
https://google-bidout-d.openx.net/w/1.0/rc?ts=2DAABBgABAAECAAIBAAsAAgAAAfEcGApJMHV0RElGdVEzHBaMqvq5xZqR17IBFuuLvKGkrvnK0wEAHBaTx72i0bCsyfgBFo3r1NOzl8mt7wEAFpaNk9gLFQYALBwVAgAcFQIAHBUCAAAcJrrv5YMEFQQVBCa47-WDBBbsy9WDBNaaARaaARaaARZkFmQWZBZkFsIBABwcLBaAsYqku-yDrSoW67K12efigOelAQAAFpTZmIAEFoC9m4AEFryx3oMEFqax3oMEFRgcFPQDFNgEABUEJsIBFsIBFsIBETUOACwsFsv6va627-DxMha3tNid58LglfABABaWjZPYCwYolNmYgAQWgL2bgAQWprHegwQWvLHegwQYFFNxS2YySG9CaHZ2dVFUbVdJUG40JsIBJQQWKBgHYWRwaWxvdBUClqrAhQMRERgCT1gMehT4AxTeBAAoA3J0YoEADDwYb2h0dHA6Ly9ncmVlbi5lcm5lLmNvL29wZW54L25vdGlmeT9pZD1oekg1bDR1XzU1R3g2cjVtS1owOEhKZ2thd1JQdXpZY3k0NFhDV1BEZEpVZmxFcVBNQ0pnaGcmd3A9JHtBVUNUSU9OX1BSSUNFfSg1c3RhcmJvZHlwb3NpdGl2ZS5ldUB0cmVuZC1jaGFzZXIuY29tQGNhbm9vZGxlc291cC5jb20AAAA&r=https://green.erne.co/clicks?id=hzH5l4u_55Gx6r5mKZ08HJgkawRPuzYcy44XCWPDdJUflEqPMCJghg&url=https%3A%2F%2Ffr.starbodypositive.eu%2F%3Faid%3D1307%26ac%3D-lESO7p6FY92JiaiixhDC-openx%26rh%3Dworkplace.stackexchange.com%26cid%3DSqKf2HoBhvvuQTmWIPn4%26cp%3D20190918_seMC26sVAdIpRl749ZiR
```

As one can guess even without speaking any French, it's some "doctors say this weight loss method is amazing" pile of crap (plus, it's animated). Can it please be removed?

---

Just got one more, on ELU, Travel and the Workplace. It appears to be from the same site. Is there more to it or should I just blame caching?

> [image: yet another weight loss ad]

```
https://google-bidout-d.openx.net/w/1.0/rc?ts=2DAABBgABAAECAAIBAAsAAgAAAdUcGApUbVlMWXZheE1LHBbj9aWt2ZuH42cW08-nu4D4i8b6AQAcFq6Yov7e_YKWIBbb2Zv5teeWrbcBABb0h5XYCxUGACwcFQIAHBUCABwVAgAAHCa67-WDBBUEFQQmuO_lgwQW7MvVgwTWZBZkFmQWZBZkFmQWZBZ0ABwcLBaAsYqku-yDrSoW67K12efigOelAQAAFpTZmIAEFoC9m4AEFryx3oMEFqax3oMEFRgcFPQDFNgEABUEJnQWdBZ0ETUOACwsFrvivfX084LKkQEW0ZD8qoG8sJ6nAQAW9IeV2AsGKJTZmIAEFoC9m4AEFqax3oMEFryx3oMEGBRFSXduU2VqeURNVEdSaGlXMWg3WiZ0JQQWEBgHYWRwaWxvdBUClqrAhQMRERgCT1gMehT4AxTeBAAoA3J0YoEADDwYb2h0dHA6Ly9ncmVlbi5lcm5lLmNvL29wZW54L25vdGlmeT9pZD1pZXExNzhPTk1RZ2QzX0tDR2RZb3UyZUt3QjlyQ1JUOU1CSTZleENtLXdCOXJsVlZNZDRYSmcmd3A9JHtBVUNUSU9OX1BSSUNFfSgic3RhcmJvZHlwb3NpdGl2ZS5ldUBnaXZlaXRsb3ZlLmNvbQAAAA&r=https://green.erne.co/clicks?id=ieq178ONMQgd3_KCGdYou2eKwB9rCRT9MBI6exCm-wB9rlVVMd4XJg&url=https%3A%2F%2Ffr.starbodypositive.eu%2F%3Faid%3D1307%26ac%3D-UJYSzt34tKODRcAy2eto-openx%26rh%3Denglish.stackexchange.com%26cid%3DEIwnSejyDMTGRhiW1h7Z%26cp%3D20190918_KFaOw50xGiJfhmK5Eu9I
```

---

<sup>1</sup> I don't have an account on The Workplace, and would rather not create one for a single meta post.

Comment: Wasn't Google fined by the French this year? It is payback time ...

Comment: Hi, Are you still getting ads when browsing with Fr culture.

Comment: @xdtTransform hi, yeah I'm still getting some, though not the spam ones above. Why?

Comment: Humm interesting. I have been reporting ads every day. But I don't them anymore on my VM, without any adblock. But getting ads everywhere else. I have stoppped my daily report because I thought there where no more ads. It was over.

Comment: @xdtTransform for what it's worth, I mostly browse on mobile, and often on stacks where I see reduced ads to begin with, so maybe I'm not a good test sample. You might want to ask in [French.SE's chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1098/chez-cosette), surely more people will be able to answer

Answer (score 12):

Thank you for reporting this ad.  We will remove it from all properties immediately.

Comment: Even if you remove this one, what steps are you going to take to *prevent such ads in the future*? Removing bad ads after someone notice and reports is meaningless if there's constant stream of bad ads.

Comment: Ah, my bad; seems someone else had posted it [on the main announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/333455/398063) already. Though the present question got acted faster. Terry, please, what's the preferred way to report to you guys? Is posting the report as a new question easier for the staff to handle?

Comment: Please check the updated post - there might be more to it, or it might just be me having to blame caching.

Comment: As long as you keep using shady ad providers, this will keep happening.