# Is the list on selfserve-stackexchange.com the complete list of sites that carry display ads?

Tags: support, advertising

The [selfserve ad campaign](https://www.selfserve-stackexchange.com/) site got an update and is now offering ads for more than just the trilogy. It currently lists:

> Stack Overflow, 
>   Server Fault,
>   Super User,
>   Android Enthusiasts,
>   Arqade,
>   Ask Different,
>   Ask Ubuntu,
>   Blender,
>   Code Review,
>   Database Administrators,
>   Drupal Answers,
>   Electrical Engineering,
>   Game Development,
>   GIS,
>   Information Security,
>   Magento,
>   Raspberry Pi,
>   Salesforce,
>   Sharepoint,
>   Software Engineering,
>   Unix and Linux,
>   User Experience,
>   Web Applications,
>   Wordpress

Comparing with the older list in [We're enabling display ads on select Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/287242/were-enabling-display-ads-on-select-stack-exchange-sites)  I notice the absence of Cross Validated. Does this mean Cross Validated will no longer carry display ads? They appear there as of now:

[image]

As an aside, "Wordpress" is missing an important part of its name (and an uppercase letter, too): the site name is [WordPress Development](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Whoaaaaaa

Nice catch! We currently offer a targeting set called "Run of Network," which allows advertisers to target all of the sites you mention above, less Cross Validated. Why is Cross Validated not included? Because CV users (and the site subject itself) are enough of a deviation from the rest that we thought it best for both the users and our advertising partners to separate it out.

When setting up the latest version of our self-serve option that went live on 1 October, we simply used the list of sites included in Run of Network, and forgot to include CV. Advertisements are still available on Cross Validated, and in fact, as a result of your eagle eyes-- it's being added to self-serve as I type this!

Finally, the change from Wordpress to WordPress Development is now live!

A personal aside: I am a pedant and stickler for details and I didn't notice the WordPress Development issue at first but it feels *exceptionally* satisfying to fix that one! :-D

As always: we appreciate your sharp eyes and kind support! Thank you!

---

**Edit**: to actually *answer* your question: that list *wasn't* the exhaustive list of all sites currently offering display advertising, but now it is! :-)

Comment: CV got inserted between trilogy sites, so the list goes "SO, CV, SU, SF, then all others alphabetized". Looks odd.