# Empty ads frame creating extra whitespace

Tags: bug, questions, design, advertising, whitespace

**Update:**

@Kevin made a very good observation [in a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310491/extra-whitespace-between-question-title-and-text#comment1014344_310491). Looking at the Chrome inspector, it looks like this is an empty Google ads frame.

[image: Chrome inspector with empty ads frame]

**Original post:**

I've noticed on a couple SE sites that I am seeing a large gap of whitespace between the title of the question and the start of the text. It appears to happen on all questions on the main site, but not the meta. It doesn't affect all of the SE sites, and the only two sites I have seen this problem on are [SFF](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/) and [RPG](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/). I am using Windows 10 and Chrome 66.0.

I also checked this in IE. The problem happens on the same sites but it also happened on [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/) before I logged in. After logging in the problem went away for The Workplace only.

I have tried this on another work computer and gotten the same results, but these two computers are under the same group policy.

[image: Whitespace bug]

Comment: I can't reproduce this (I'm running Windows 10 and Chrome 66.0 as well). Do you have any userscripts running? Also, when did this start?

Comment: @Null I don't believe I have any scripts running. This is a work computer, so I may not be aware of everything going on in the background. I started noticing this within the past day or two. I tried recreating on IE and saw the same problem, and it affected at least one other site it wasn't affecting in Chrome.

Comment: Have you seen it only on your work computer or does it occur on another computer (like your home computer)?

Comment: I have not tried it on another computer, but I can when I get home today.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of at the moment is that it's a blocked ad, but I don't think they're shown there. Do you know how to inspect elements on the page (Ctrl-Shift-I in Chrome)? Any unusual elements there?

Comment: @Null I'm not super familiar, but I did take a look. See my edit.

Comment: Hmm, I see that googletagservices script between container and footer on some questions but not others...but I don't see whitespace between the title and question body on any questions.

Comment: @Null Yeah, that might be a red herring and just coincidence that I picked sites with and without it. I did just notice on Arqade that the whitespace gap actually has an ad in it, so maybe it is an adblocker issue.

Comment: The whitespace seems to be a div that I only get in a private session in FireFox, not logged in, but not in a private session in Opera, logged in. `<style>.everyoneloves__top-leaderboard:empty,.everyoneloves__mid-leaderboard:empty{                height:90px;width:728px;box-sizing:border-box;
}</style><div id="dfp-tlb" class="everyonelovesstackoverflow everyoneloves__top-leaderboard"></div>` After logging in in FireFox, the div is gone.

Comment: Just to confirm, SFF is not on [the list of sites with ads](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/287242/were-enabling-display-ads-on-select-stack-exchange-sites).

Comment: @SOLO I don't think that list is current, because I'm seeing ads on [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/332761/what-are-subspecies-and-varients-in-monster-hunter), but that site isn't listed either.

Comment: @DavidK Ah. Hm. Further searching turns up "Because it has been successful so far, we're going to be extending the program to the majority of our graduated sites. Well, we've _pretty much_ already done that, but there are quite a few sites that have ads enabled, yet still display nothing." -[Tim Post, 2018-02-07](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306737/affiliate-ads-are-coming-to-the-network)

Comment: [Chrome's inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqiQI.png) shows it as an empty google ads iframe. Empty, not blocked.

Comment: This also appears on Travel.SE

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yeah.. this is my fault. The settings about which ad zones to "collapse" when an ad is not served by Google DFP got lost in a recent refactor.

Fix is going out shortly, thanks.

Comment: Appears to be fixed - thanks!