# Can we have a drop-down menu for "Featured on Meta"?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, voting, featured-tag

UPDATE (02/09/2019) It has been <strike>over 26</strike> 32 days since [Congratulations to our 29 oldest beta sites - They're now no longer beta!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331708/congratulations-to-our-29-oldest-beta-sites-theyre-now-no-longer-beta?cb=1) appeared on **Featured on Meta**.

The news was great,  99% of users who viewed the announcement celebrated.  Everybody appreciated the work and zeal that achieved this long overdue decision. As of today, 454 users have cast an upvote. The post itself has attracted over 81,000 views, so safe to say that the news is... “old”?

I don't remember an announcement on Meta staying up so many weeks, maybe this is not so exceptional. But seeing the question on the EL&U main page, for over a month, seems that nothing else has happened in the meantime, when we all know that is not true.

[image] [image]

P.S I did post a comment asking the Community Manager responsible, to elucidate or hint when the question would no longer be featured but for some reason it got deleted.

### FEATURE REQUEST

If the **Featured on Meta** box had a drop-down menu, users could see other posts that deserve viewing and the casting of votes. One question in particular, which I think merited a larger audience is

[Let's take a look at the interaction between staff and the "power users" of the network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331513/lets-take-a-look-at-the-interaction-between-staff-and-the-power-users-of-the)

It has earned 150 upvotes but it has been viewed only 2,000 times.

Is adding a drop menu prohibitive? Has anyone else thought of this feature? In any case, the question is also asking *when* the team will replace the 27-day-old announcement.

*Variety is the spice of life* etc.

Comment: As to when the featured tag will disappear: as far as I remember, featured tags are automatically removed by the Community user after 30 days. So hang in there just a little longer ;)

Comment: There have also been declined flags for attempts to get other posts featured so I guess it is up to SE staff what we get to see there. I don't think that CB box is primarily meant to drive users to *other posts that deserve viewing and the casting of votes*. Its only design goal is to bring eyes to a specific post. Regular users are supposed to use the front-page, newest or active tab, or custom question lists.

Comment: @rene a CB box is...? Community...? True what you say about the scope of feature on meta, it's to draw attention to a specific notice, that can announce  a competition, a significant change  on the platform that will affect every user or an innovative piece of design. But sometimes these events can overlap, and a drop-down menu means a handy **preview** of the most noteworthy news for everyone across the network. When a post is important and as well written, such as Mithrandir's , I think MSE should feature it. It doesn't have to have top billing, but it deserves more exposure.

Comment: I meant *CB* to be short for "Community Bulletin", basically the thing we talk about. Maybe that initialism is only used by me, sorry about that.

Comment: @Mari-LouA compared to MSO in which they disabled the automatic "feature on meta" and has to manually request a post to be featured, I never hear the same policy for MSE (allowing MSE mods to feature a community post), which will also affect the whole network...

Comment: What do you mean by drop down? Do you mean something that says “click to show” and then shows the titles?

Comment: @Laurel yes? Click on a word or icon and a drop-down menu appears. Like when you click on the hamburger icon.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell that 29 sites have left beta announcement. It's still being featured. How come? More than 30 days have gone by. Is it because it's still a Sunday in the US? But yesterday was the 1st September.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Hey, that's strange... I don't know why it's still there, it should be gone after 30 days, for all I know.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell what's going on here? At this point, I definitely think a drop menu is a necessity.  Is there a reason why this feature cannot be introduced anytime in the future?

Comment: @Mari-LouA the current guessing is that [there's a process that runs on Saturdays](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7884456#7884456), that removes these tags (rene did a SEDE search). As for the limitations of SE, those elude me. Remember, I'm just a mod, not staff...