# Are more than two featured posts from this site (Meta.SE) supposed to appear on community bulletins on main Q&A sites now?

Tags: support, community-bulletin, featured-tag

Per the [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130893/377214) to [What criteria are used to select the links that appear in the community bulletin sidebar block?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/130621/377214), only two featured posts on Meta Stack Exchange can appear in the community bulletin sidebar:

> Additionally, **up to two** [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) posts from Meta Stack Exchange will appear in the community bulletins of all main sites

However, I just looked at The Workplace's community bulletin now, and there are *three* featured posts from Meta Stack Exchange, *in addition* to two from its per-site meta:

> [image: Excessively long community bulletin]

Is this a bug, or is this an intentional change made at some point? Or is there a manual exception being made that will be removed once these featured posts run their course and are un-featured?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We temporarily bumped the max to 3 to allow for both the community relations/roadmap posts and the maintenance notice to be up at the same time.

Comment: Most "temporary changes" stick for good. Just saying, it can stay. :-)

Comment: @ShadowWizardisEarForYou I don't know, it's starting to look pretty busy over there... check out [Sustainability.SE], where we've also got elections going (adding two posts).