# Can I access Area 51 from the Stack Exchange app?

Tags: support, area-51

I'm trying to access Area 51 from my Stack Exchange app. But it is not showing any options to go.

Is Area 51 accessible from the app?

Comment: Nope, you need to use a browser.

Comment: @DanBron any reason?

Comment: @hanugm the app has been abandoned for a really, really long time. It wasn't supported for whatever reason, and there's not going to be put any work into it

Comment: @hanugm reason it's not showing Area 51? Because Area 51 is very old, and written in a different code base which is not supported by the backend of the app.

Comment: @Zoe the transgirl: Likely due to [the November 2017 mass layoff](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7926678#7926678). [Another source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331513).

Comment: @PeterMortensen they still claim (claim because I really have no idea if it's true - I've lost trust in the people saying it) to have 250 employees. The layoff resulting in multiple products not being developed when they clearly have more than enough people is weird